# How to start a docker Powershell container interactively which was stopped before

Tags: docker, powershell

I need to try out some stuff with Powershell on Linux. I have created a docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -it --name pwsh mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-centos-8
```

This works as expected and i have an interactive shell i can work with. But i want to reuse it after i have stopped the container.

I have tried the following:

```
docker start -ia pswh
```

But this just starts the container and immediately stops it. Any Ideas how i can again enter an interactive session?

Answer (score 0):

While i don't have a solution for my own question i have made a workaround and used the .NET SDK container image which comes with powershell included.

Answer (score -1):

You can start the container by executing the following command in interactive mode:

```
docker -it pswh /bin/bash
```

Comment: This command does nothing. Could you please explain a bit more.